# Laravel mails events have en empty message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, sparkpost

I'm sending an email like :

```
Mail::to($to)->queue($mailable);
```

I have a listener like that (registered in EventServiceProvider) :

```
class LogSendingMessage
{

    public function __construct(){}

    public function handle($event): void
    {
        dd($event);
    }
}
```

It print something like :

```
{
    "message":{},
    "data":{"locale":"fr","primaryColor":"#222222", ... }
}
```

The message is empty. I'm using SparkPost, I can't get the transmissionId from SparkPost to make futur API calls.

Comment: Have you actually looked through https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#writing-mailables ? I can't see you actually declaring or passing the body to the mail event anywhere.

Comment: Could we see the mailable? Also probably how you constructed it?